# Finding matching rows from original dataset in an slightly reduced version of itself

Tags: matlab

I have two datasets, the original have all the labels and description of each variable, but the second is a reduced version of this dataset, used for specifics experiments, but don't have any of the information about the variables, contained in the original. So, I'm trying to match both datasets.

My question here is how can I find if a row from the original dataset is present in the new dataset, if a slight data reduction have been performed in both matrix dimensions?

Being more specific, the original dataset is a 24481 x 117 matrix and the new one is a 24188 x 97 matrix. However, the problem here is that I have no information of which rows or columns were or were not included in the new dataset

Comment: So how did you go from rows of 117 elements to rows of 97 elements? Did you simply clip off the last 20 elements? The first 20?

Comment: They cut off the rows and columns in the original dataset with a specific loss of data (e.g > 15 % of values are 0), but this information is not provided.

Comment: But was it a block of 20 columns that got removed from the original matrix or was it a random set of 20 columns? The missing rows are irrelevant to your question.

Comment: A random set of 20 rows and 293 columns have been removed. The problem here is that I have no information of which rows or columns were or were not included in the new dataset.

Comment: Okay, then it's gonna be tricky, and the solution posted below will unfortunately not work. And i think you mean 293 rows and 20 columns were removed, assuming you used the standard `numRows x numColumns` format to specify the matrix sizes in your OP.

Comment: What kind values does the matrix take? Real values, discrete values, binary?

Comment: The matrix takes real values, and you're right about the answer already posted, I can't use it unless I find where this values are missing, and that's my goal.

Comment: Okay, I'll post a solution for you shortly, but one final question.How common is it that the same number is found in more than one row?

Comment: It is unlikely to find the same value in the same row, even in the whole dataset considering we are working with real numbers with 3-digits precision, but could not say exactly, because the dataset is very large.

I was thinking that the best solution here is a method to determine the matching percent between to variables in the dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using *intersect* function worked for me. Since a data reduction have been performed in both dimensions, first I look for the intersection of the first two columns vectors in the matrices (assuming that at least the columns order have been preserved in the reduction).

```
>> M = magic(5)

M =

  17    24     1     8    15
  23     5     7    14    16
   4     6    13    20    22
  10    12    19    21     3
  11    18    25     2     9

>> X = M([2,3,5], [1,2,4,5])

X =

  23     5    14    16
   4     6    20    22
  11    18     2     9

>> [c,xi, mi]=intersect(X(:,1),M(:,1))
```

***mi*** is  the column index vector of all rows from the original matrix M present in the reduced matrix X.
Doing the same for the two first rows in the matrices gave me a row index vector for all columns selected from the original matrix M.

```
>> [c,xi, mi]=intersect(X(1,:),M(1,:))
```

This solution has a drawback is that when the first row or column of the original matrix was not selected in the new set, then there you go moving the index of the compared vector from the original matrix, luckily not too much ;).

```
>> [c,xi, mi]=intersect(X(1,:),M(2,:))
```

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is zero pad the matrix with less number of elements so that it matches the size of the original data. then use

```
find(A==B)
```

`A` and `B` are the matrices

Comment: Thanks @Abhishek, but rows and columns in the dataset were randomly removed, so padding the matrix will require known where they are missing.